# Integral of a function which is everywhere discontinuous?

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

Yesterday, I tried to carry out a little thought experiment when it came to taking limits and have found that it has pushed my understanding of them to the breaking point. I tried considering the following scenario.

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{F}\to \mathbb{F}$ is a function which is everywhere discontinuous over the compact region $C$. Furthermore, suppose that there exists a function $g\in C^{C}$, the set of all permutations of $C$ such that $(f\circ g)(x)$ is your favorite type of continuous over $C$. Would it be unreasonable for us to say that $\int_C f=\int_C f\circ g$ by some definition of integration? Any and all insights, as well as references on similar (or identical) questions are welcome.

Comment: Not sure I follow: If C is the closed interval [0,1] and g(x) = $x^2$, Then g is a "permutation" of the points of C, no?  But your formula doesn't make sense (even for a simple function like f(x) = x).  Or am I misreading?

Comment: You would need $g $ to be ergodic for this to work as expected. Merely being a bijection is not enough.

Comment: @Ian If I understand correctly, ergodicity effectively has this built into the definition, no?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.